# Casting and Virtual functions

Tags: c++

I am working around casting and virtual functions. I have a base class called `Base`and a derived class called `Derived` with public inheritance. Between the base and the derived class I have a function named `Show` that has virtual behavior:

```
Derived clientsD = Derived(" Rui Pedro", 2000, 50.00);  
Derived* PclientsD -> &clientsD;
Base* clientesB =(Base*) PclientsD; 
clientesB -> Show();
```

The code works but the called function is the one redefined in the derived class and not the `Base` class `Show` function?
I was expecting to view the Base class `Show` and not the derived one since I made the casting. This is also the behavior if I cast a derived pointer to a base class pointer. When I make the casting the pointer conversion should print the base class function in spite of virtual behavior. That was what I expected to view without the scope resolution operator `clientesB -> Base::Show();`.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please [edit] your post to clarify.

Comment: This is how virtual function works. What's your question?

Comment: The point of virtual function is that a concrete implementation is used when made available. What you're doing (albeit somewhat unclear and under-explained) seems like the expected behaviour of a concretized virtual to me.

Answer (score 3):

The derived `Show` is called because you've marked it `virtual` in `Base`.

If you don't want that behaviour, then either drop the `virtual` or use the *scope resolution operator* and call

```
clientesB->Base::Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have used `virtual` in your function declaration in the base class.